# What does the following error message mean "error: invalid operands to binary expression ('double' and 'double')"?

Tags: c, debugging, cs50

It occurred when I tried to implement "%" operator in C while using float for input.
I am enrolled in cs50 course and this is the fourth problem of problem set 1 that I am trying.

Here's the code

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("O hai! How much change is owed?\n");
    float x = get_float();
    if(x % 0.25 == 0)
    {
        printf("%.55f\n", x/0.25);
    }

    else if(x % 0.10 == 0)
    {
        printf("%.55f\n", x/0.10);
    }

    else if(x % 0.05 == 0)
    {
        printf("%.55f\n", x/0.05);
    }

    else if(x % 0.01 == 0)
    {
        printf("%.55f\n", x/0.01);
    }

}
```

Comment: I used fmod instead of % but it gives error "greedy.c:8:10: error: expected ')'
    if(x fmod 0.25 == 0)"
         ^

Comment: use `if(fmod(x,0.25) == 0.0)`

Answer (score 0):

Modulo operator (%) returns the remainder of the division operation and it is applicable only for whole numbers (C equivalent data types int, short, long). Since you are trying to perform this operation on a non-whole number(Floating point number) compiler is not allowing you to compile the program and throwing an error.

Comment: so is there another way to get the same result while using float or double double